# Getting Error while trying to run chrome using chromedriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to invoke chrome from ruby console.

I am using command - `Watir::Browser.new :chrome`

I have ruby -  **ruby 1.9.3p484**

I have installed gems and the version of **watir-wedriver** is - **watir-webdriver (0.6.11)**

The version of chrome is - **44.0.2403.157**

I have chromedriver version - **v2.9.248304**

Can somebody point if I am doing something wrong here. Not sure what to do google does not seems to help and I am a new to ruby and scripting.

I am getting below error when I try to start chrome -

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64)

from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:71:in `assert_ok'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `new'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `create_response'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:90:in `request'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:657:in `raw_execute'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:122:in `create_session'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:87:in `initialize'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:48:in `initialize'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:56:in `new'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:56:in `for'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:86:in `for'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
from (irb):3:in `new'
from (irb):3
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'irb(main):004:0>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was my machine did not have the display driver so when I was trying to run chrome it was failing. One more thing I tried headless also using chrome driver but the issue there was I was not having enough permissions for headless gems to run. Thus changing the permission made my task easy and now I am able to run selenium scripts using ruby.

IF anyone has any other doubt in this area you can send me a personal message here or just comment on this one will try to response.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, there may be 2 reasons

1. Chromedriver is not properly set in PATH variable OR
2. You are missing DISPLAY parameter environment variable.

Please go through this post, it may be useful to you to understand DISPLAY parameter :
[Selenium web driver DISPLAY variable value](http://artechspot.com/posts/selenium-selenium-webdriver-error-webdrivererror)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to give the display parameter, I will try this. As the option 1 is not applicable for me I have set the PATH variable for chromedriver

Comment: As mentioned in post, you can set variable value by  `export DISPLAY=:0`

Comment: This is also not working. I have added the DISPLAY in environment variable.